# how to keep a SignalR connection alive in react native application even when the device is in sleep mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, signalr, background-task

I have a signalR connection with specific configuration.I write a provider in order to create a connection instance and serve that connection to all components in my app (using react context). Creating a connection instance is done inside a class and this connection instance is somehow singelton.
then by using a package called

> react-native-background-timer

I follow the document and create a util function in order to run starting connection task in background.

here is all the staff i've done :

signalR Class:

```
class SignalR {
private static instance: SignalR;
connection: HubConnection | undefined;
private appGuid: string;
private mobileNumber: string;
private countryCode: string;

private constructor(
appGuid: string,
mobileNumber: string,
countryCode: string,
  ) {
this.appGuid = appGuid;
this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
this.countryCode = countryCode;
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(`${config.api.url}/hub/notificationhub`, {
    headers: {
      AppGuid: this.appGuid,
      AppPhoneNumber: this.mobileNumber,          
      AppCountryCode: this.countryCode,
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    logMessageContent: true,
    transport: 1,
    skipNegotiation: true,
     })
   .build();
    }

     public static getInstance(appGuid: string, mobileNumber: string): SignalR {
       if (!SignalR.instance) {
        SignalR.instance = new SignalR(appGuid, mobileNumber);
       }  
        if (this.instance.connection?.state === 'Disconnected') {
              SignalR.instance.start();
           }
            return SignalR.instance;
        }


 start() {
     console.log('this is start');
      this.connection
          ?.start()
         .then(res => {
          console.log('SignalR connection started successfuly');
         })
           .catch(err => {
              console.log('SignalR connection not started: ', err);
          });
            }

    stop() {           
          this.connection?.stop();
            }
      }

      export default SignalR;
```

this is Provider :

```
export const SignalRProvider = ({children, otpObject}: any) => {
 const {appGuid, mobileNumber,countryCode } = otpObject;

 const signalr = SignalR.getInstance(appGuid, mobileNumber,countryCode ); 

 const restartConnection = () => {
   if (signalr.connection?.state === 'Disconnected') {
     signalr.start();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
       const intervalId = backgroundTask(restartConnection);
    }, []);

  return (
      <SignalRContext.Provider value={{connection: signalr.connection}}>
         {children}
      </SignalRContext.Provider>
   );
 };
```

and this is utils which takes a function and run it in background:

```
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

  const backgroundTask = (someTask: any) => {
  const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
  someTask();
    }, 30000);

   return intervalId;
 };

  export default backgroundTask;
```

All I want is to keep this background task running when device goes in sleep mode,
if I could do this it means that I have stable connection.

Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance.